# I am having problems with related content

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I'm dealing with the movie application and the movies are sorted according to their id numbers in the related content section and the related content does not change in any movie. Can you help?

```
  //----related rv----------
                relatedAdapter = new HomePageAdapter(this, listRelated, PreferenceUtils.isMandatoryLogin(configViewModel));
                rvRelated.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,
                  reverselayout:false));
                rvRelated.setHasFixedSize(true);
                rvRelated.setAdapter(relatedAdapter);

                if (categoryType.equals("tvseries")) {

                    seasonSpinnerContainer.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                    rvServer.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                    serverIv.setVisibility(GONE);

                    rvRelated.removeAllViews();
                    listRelated.clear();
                    rvServer.removeAllViews();
                    listServer.clear();
                    listServer.clear();

                    downloadBt.setVisibility(GONE);
                    watchNowBt.setVisibility(GONE);
                    trailerBt.setVisibility(GONE);
```

```
  //----related tv series---------------
                    for (int i = 0; i < singleDetails.getRelatedTvseries().size(); i++) {
                        RelatedMovie relatedTvSeries = singleDetails.getRelatedTvseries().get(i);

                        CommonModels models = new CommonModels();
                        models.setTitle(relatedTvSeries.getTitle());
                        models.setImageUrl(relatedTvSeries.getThumbnailUrl());
                        models.setId(relatedTvSeries.getVideosId());
                        models.setVideoType("tvseries");
                        models.setIsPaid(relatedTvSeries.getIsPaid());
                        listRelated.add(models);
                    }

                    if (listRelated.size() == 0) {
                        tvRelated.setVisibility(GONE);
                    }
```

reverselayout I tried several techniques but couldn't show the movie in the last id. This time it showed backwards from ID 24.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.